# MySQL Temporary Tables

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, temporary-tables

I am facing Memory issue in our server. While debugging I came to know that, many number (millions) of temporary tables are created. **Is there any way to identify which databases are creating this temporary tables?** We have around 50 databases and many of the databases using **`create temporary table`** statement in its procedures. In `/tmp` directory I could see the `.ibd`, `.frm` and few `.MYI` & `MYD` files. **Is it possible to find which database contributing more to creation of temporary tables?** Please let me know, if you need any other information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite what you asked for, but this query may help:

```
mysql> SELECT db, name FROM mysql.proc WHERE body LIKE '%temporary%';
+---------------+-----------------------------------+
| db            | name                              |
+---------------+-----------------------------------+
| common_schema | rdebug_compile_routine            |
| common_schema | _get_sql_dependencies_internal    |
| common_schema | query_checksum                    |
| common_schema | _split_cleanup_dependency_tables  |
| common_schema | _split_generate_dependency_tables |
+---------------+-----------------------------------+
```

If `/tmp` is in a separate filesystem, you are cruisin' for a bruisin'.  Change `tmpdir` to point to some directory in the main FS.